# How can we fix the instructional text so it does not stay permanent?

Tags: excel, vba, text

So I have a code that put instructional text in several cells (C9, C10, C18, C26 and C32). The instructional text disappears after a second if you don't stay on the cell. The problem is, my text is gray and my text is always instructional even when I click on it again after. I would like it to be gray when instructional, but black when the client will put is info and that it stays so he can correct his answer if he needs to.

My code for now is :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
listecellules = "/" & Range("C9").Address & "/" & Range("C10").Address & "/" & Range("C18").Address & "/" & Range("C26").Address & "/" & Range("C32").Address & "/"
If listecellules Like "*/" & Target.Address & "/*" Then
If Target <> "" Then
texte = Target.Value
Target = ""
temps_début = Timer
    Do While Timer < temps_début + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop
If Target = "" Then
Target.Value = texte
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Edit : texte is text in french, temps-debut is time-start in french, listescellules is Cells list whitout space in french.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having with your current code?

Comment: The text disappear when you click on it, but the format is permanent, if the client needs to correct a mistake he can't because the text that you put always disappear. Can we make it stop after the first text is enter so it becomes more natural ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more complex but worked for me:

In the worksheet code module:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const RNG_INSTRUCT As String = "C9,C18,C26,C32"
    Const INSTRUCT = "Blah blah blah"
    
    'need to exit?
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(RNG_INSTRUCT)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If col Is Nothing Then Set col = New Collection 'if not yet created...
    
    col.Add Array(Target.Address, Target.Value) 'store address and current value
    With Target
        .Font.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200) 'set grey font
        .Value = INSTRUCT                'set instructions
    End With
    
    'clear instructions after 2 seconds and restore any original value
    '   `ClearInstruct` is in a regular module
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2), _
        "'ClearInstruct(""" & Target.Address & """)'", _
        schedule:=True
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public col As Collection  'stores any selected cells

Public Sub ClearInstruct(addr As String)
    Dim i As Long, tmp
    Debug.Print "Ran with", addr
    If col Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For i = col.Count To 1 Step -1  'check for any cells to restore
        tmp = col(i)
        If tmp(0) = addr Then       'address matches?
            '##change `Sheet4` to your actual sheet codename
            With Sheet4.Range(addr) 'restore font color and value
                .Font.Color = vbBlack
                .Value = tmp(1)
            End With
            col.remove i            'remove from collection
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly how does it  "not work"? do you get an error?  If Yes, what is the error?